# Joining strings using separator in Java

Tags: java

I have an object called MyDate and it return three methods `String getDay(), String getYear(), String getMonth()`

For example Sep 24 2013 will 2013, 24, 9 .. I want to join these three strings using a common separator which is DASH `"-".` How do I join without using StringBuilder or "+" operator ? What would be the most compact code form ?

For e.g I know I can do this  but is there a more compact form ? Because I know + operator is expensive.

```
MyDate myDate = new MyDate();
myDate.getYear()+"-"+myDate.getMonth()+"-"+myDate.getDay();
```

Comment: You don't want to use `+` or `StringBuilder`?

Comment: I'd say use a StringBuilder, but you exluded that.  How come?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `String.format(...)`

For example, if your getXXX() methods return a Strings:

```
String dateStr = String.format("%s-%s-%s", 
      myDate.getYear(), myDate.getMonth(), myDate.gateDay());
```

Else if they return an int:

```
String dateStr = String.format("%4d-%02d-%02d", 
      myDate.getYear(), myDate.getMonth(), myDate.gateDay());
```

For more on this, check out any tutorial on the `printf(...)` method or the Formatter object.

Answer (score 2):

You can be ***cool*** and use Guava

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date myDate = new Date();
    Object[] objects = new Object[] {
            myDate.getYear(), myDate.getMonth(), myDate.getDay()
    };
    String message = Joiner.on("-").join(objects);
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

Comment: One suspects that Guava uses StringBuilder.

Comment: @user949300 Yeah, but it's hidden!

Comment: I like your solution, or the Apache commons suggestions, assuming that OP is already using them in his codebase.

Comment: Wish `Joiner.on("-").join(objects);` was named `Joiner.join(objects).using("-");`

Answer (score 2):

If you're not opposed to using Apache commons.

`StringUtils#join`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use apache commons then `String concatenate(Object[] array)` would be perfect.
You can give your strings in one go :

```
StringUtils.concatenate([myDate.getYear(), myDate.getMonth(), myDate.gateDay()])
```

More info here :
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Comment: Don't you need a separator somewhere in there? Also that method is deprecated.